# Anime where the main character finds a card with a red aura in a box inside a shop

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching this anime on YouTube around 2010-2020.

The main character (MC) went to buy a gift for his mother but found a card (I believe it was a fire card) in a box. There was a scene before the MC goes to buy the gift for his mother where he was in some kind of card competition and there were two people -- one fat and the other skinny and short -- who were trying recruit him (I think, but I'm  not sure).

I think there's a evil organization whose name has something to do with dragons. The MC is in the good organization whose name has something to do with tigers. His mother disappeared and finding her becomes the MC's driving force (I think, but I'm not sure). There's a character with blue hair named Fin and I'm pretty sure that they're trying to recover battle cards like the fire cards found by the MC.

Answer (score 5):

This is ***[Tai Chi Chasers](https://myanimelist.net/anime/7522/Taichi_Senjimon)*** (2007-2008).

> After a strange and devastating attack on his home, a young boy named Rai is shocked to discover he's a secret descendent of the Tigeroids: an ancient race of peaceful beings locked in a struggle with the ruthless and cunning Dragonoids. In a parallel universe called Suhn, the Tigeroids and Dragonoids are battling furiously to recover 500 lost tai chi characters. Whoever retrieves these precious and potent symbols will possess the ultimate power to rule their realm…and destroy their enemies. As Rai hones his innate tai chi skills to fight the Dragonoids, he must find the lost tai chi and battle to become one of the champion Tai Chi Chasers!

At the start of the first episode, we're introduced to the [Tigeroids](https://taichisenjimon.fandom.com/wiki/Tigeroid) and [Dragonoids](https://taichisenjimon.fandom.com/wiki/Dragonoid), ancient races who've come to Earth looking for lost [Tai Chi Cards](https://taichisenjimon.fandom.com/wiki/Tai_Chi_Symbols), which they use to initiate special attacks. The Tigeroids are mainly represented by four kids, including a blue-haired boy named [Finn](https://taichisenjimon.fandom.com/wiki/Finn), who refer to themselves as the Tai Chi Chasers.

Soon after, we meet the main character, [Rai Gherba](https://taichisenjimon.fandom.com/wiki/Rai_Gherba), a boy competing in a card-stacking competition in order to win money to buy his mother a birthday present. One of the other contestants is a fat boy with whom Rai has an ongoing rivalry; that boy has a couple of skinny friends watching from the sidelines. Rai wins the competition and then visits a shop to buy a jewellery box for his mother.

When he gets home, he's attacked by a Dragonoid. His mother intervenes and locks him out of the house while she confronts the Dragonoid, but the house explodes and only the Dragonoid remains. Rai then discovers that he himself is a Tigeroid and that the box he purchased contains a [Fire Tai Chi Card](https://taichichasers.fandom.com/wiki/Fire_Cards), which he uses against the Dragonoid. The other four Tigeroid kids show up and help him defeat the Dragonoid, after which they recruit him.

> 

Comment: Yes,thank you so much that is correct

Comment: @Jack - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.